# How Java represent min value of a number type? for example -128 in byte

Tags: java, memory, byte, primitive-types

For example :
Byte primitive data type has 8 bits. It Supports -128 to +127. One bit is a sign bit, so when all bits are 1 and sign bit is 0, represent +127, and when all bits are 0 and sign bit is 1, it can show -127, how represent -128?

Comment: -127 is `1000 0001`, -128 is `1000 0000`.

Comment: java consider the sign bit as value bit ? 
I can't understand. 1000 0000 after 2's complement and without considering the sign bit is -127. So how does it work?  @rgettman

Comment: The "sign bit" is really just a value of `-128` for bytes.

Comment: So, the sign bit actually has a negative weight. correct?